# UIPickerView selected value is is covered by black label

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uipickerview

I'm working on iOS native app. Its design contains UIPickerView with UIImageView (show in below screenshot) placed over it.

[image: UIPickerSkin]

This should display UIPickerView with image placed over it. However, I'm getting black color band on PickerView instead of light grey.

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

Below is code that I have used

```
    self.objPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, (screenHeight-statusBarFrame.size.height-216.0),screenWidth,216.0)];
    self.pickerSkin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.objPickerView.frame];               

    [self.objScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.objPickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [self.pickerSkin setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PickerSkinColor"]];
    [self.objScrollView addSubview:self.objPickerView];
    [self.objScrollView addSubview:self.pickerSkin];
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: First screenshot is your image?

Comment: @pandarencodemaster : Image name as "PickerSkinColor" with png format

Comment: Are you sure that the image is being added to the bundle?